# Ionic 2 - Any type variables

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Estou com problema na migração do ionic beta.11 para RC0. Toda vez que eu coloco um construtor esperando o tipo "any" obtenho o seguinte erro.

> ngc error: Error: Error at
>   /Projeto/.tmp/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts:456:134: Property 'any' does
>   not exist on type 'typeof "/Projeto/.tmp/directives/mask"'.

Ao ir no app.module.ngfactory.ts na linha 456 ele gera a linha abaixo:

```
if ((this.__MaskDirective_75 == (null as any))) { (this.__MaskDirective_75 = new import45.MaskDirective(this.parent.get(import45.any),this.parent.get('mask'))); }
```

Segue abaixo o código da minha diretiva:

```
import {Directive, Attribute} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[mask]',
    host: {
        '(keyup)': 'onInputChange()'
    }
})
export class MaskDirective {
    maskPattern: string;
    placeHolderCounts: number;
    dividers: string[];
    modelValue: string;
    viewValue: string;

    constructor(
        public model: any,
        @Attribute("mask") maskPattern: string
    ) {
        this.dividers = maskPattern.replace(/\*/g, "").split("");
        this.dividers.push(" ");
        this.generatePattern(maskPattern);
    }

    onInputChange() {
        this.modelValue = this.getModelValue();
        var stringToFormat = this.modelValue;
        if (stringToFormat.length < 10) {
            stringToFormat = this.padString(stringToFormat);
        }

        this.viewValue = this.format(stringToFormat);
        this.model.viewToModelUpdate(this.modelValue);
        this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.viewValue)
    }

    generatePattern(patternString) {
        this.placeHolderCounts = (patternString.match(/\*/g) || []).length;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.placeHolderCounts; i++) {
            patternString = patternString.replace('*', "{" + i + "}");
        }
        this.maskPattern = patternString;
    }

    format(s) {
        var formattedString = this.maskPattern;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.placeHolderCounts; i++) {
            formattedString = formattedString.replace("{" + i + "}", s.charAt(i));
        }
        return formattedString;
    }

    padString(s) {
        var pad = "          ";
        return (s + pad).substring(0, pad.length);
    }

    getModelValue() {
        var modelValue = this.model.value;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dividers.length; i++) {
            while (modelValue.indexOf(this.dividers[i]) > -1) {
                modelValue = modelValue.replace(this.dividers[i], "");
            }
        }
        return modelValue;
    }
}
```

O que eu posso fazer para corrigir esse problema e continuar a atualização do meu projeto?

Answer (score 0):

Isto acontece pois o "sistema" de DI (dependency injection) sabe o que ele precisa injetar de acordo com o tipo do parametro no constructor().

Exemplo:

```
constructor(
    private navController: NavController, 
    private http: Http) { }
```

Assim o Angular2 sabe que tem que "dar um new" nas classes NavController e Http.

No seu caso, como está como any, ele não sabe o que injetar.
Existem algumas maneiras de resolver o seu problema.

1:
Acredito que no seu caso, você precise injetar o NgModel

```
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';
...
constructor(
    public model: NgModel,
    @Attribute("mask") maskPattern: string) {
...
}
```

2:
Dizer para o cara que gerencia as injeções de dependência (container DI), o que ele deve enviar sempre que ele precisar dar um new na classe MaskDirective.

Nesse caso não vou poder te ajudar, não encontrei nenhum exemplo prático.

**Links úteis:**

1 - [Problema relacionado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106350/attribute-directive-with-ngmodel-to-change-field-value)

2 - [Documentação @Directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

3 - [Exemplos de Injeção de Dependência](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html)